# Empirically estimating extremal coefficient using minima of Fréchet margins

Tags: distributions, extreme-value, gumbel-distribution

I recently came across a paper which uses the following formula to empirically estimate the extremal correlation coefficient $\chi_{ij}$ between two variables $x$ and $y$ as follows:
$$ \chi_{xy} = \frac{n}{\sum_i^n \min(\hat F_X(x_i), \hat F_Y(y_i))}, \qquad \text(1)$$ where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\hat F_X(x)$ is the transformation of $x$ to its Frechet marginal distribution. [This is done using](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_distribution) $$  \hat F_X(x)=-\frac{1}{\log \tilde F_X(x)} $$ where $\tilde F_X$ is the empirical distribution function of $x$. The authors provide no justification for this and I haven't been able to derive it from the formulae I know for extremal coefficient

$$ \chi_{xy} = \lim_{q \to 1} \mathbb{P} \left( F_X(x) > q | F_Y(y) > q\right) \in [0, 1],\qquad \text(2)  $$ where $q$ is a quantile, and
$$ \chi_{xy} = 2 - 2 \Phi\left(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\gamma(x,y)}\right) \qquad  \text(3)$$ where $\Phi$ is the Gaussian distribution function and $\gamma$ is the variogram function between $x$ and $y$.

Where does $\text{(1)}$ come from? How is it related to $\text{(2)}$ and $\text{(3)}$?

Comment: Could you give a reference for (1)? I suspect that (3) relates to the case where the r.vs have a max stable joint distribution, in relation with the Brown-Resnick max-stable process. There seems to be a problem of vocabulary : *extremal correlation* does not seem so common. Also, mind the difference between the *tail dependence coefficient* $\chi$ (sometimes denoted by $\lambda$) and the *extremal coefficient* often denoted by $\theta$ wit $0 \leq \theta \leq 2$.

Comment: Sorry in my previous comment, one should read $1 \leqslant \theta \leqslant 2$.

Comment: Yes, it actually does state (3) relates to the Brown-Resnick paper but I had missed that detail (I'm very new to EVT). Equations (1) and (2)  come from [this paper](http://www.karinvanderwiel.nl/Files/2022.EDS.Boulaguiem.etal.pdf) but (1) is only used in the related code in evtGAN_temperature.py [here](https://zenodo.org/record/5821485). ```def EC_est(frechet, n):
    minima = [np.min(frechet[k,:]) for k in range(n)]
    EC = n/np.sum(minima)
``` (modified to fit).

Comment: OK In the code I think that your formula (1) lacks an inverse transformation. The minimum is on the *inverses* of the two Fréchet r.vs. See my answer to come.

Comment: Also in formula (3) there is a problem of notation because is the right-hand side $x$ and $y$ are the two indices at which the max-stable process say $Z(s)$ is considered. This should be explained, although this is a somewhat distinct question than finding the relation between (1) and (2).